# Why the expression from "parse" function doesnot work to fix parameters of "ugarchfit"

Tags: r, garch

I´m writing a automatic proceso of fitting any stock-index with Garch model which involves writing a function which refines the garch model by fixing those non-significant parameters to zero.

First I attach my code for fitting stoxx50 daily price from 01/01/2015 to 31/12/2017 by GJRGarch(1,0) and ARMA(3,4) from autoarima.

```
autoarima=auto.arima(stoxx50,trace=FALSE)
lags_ar=length(autoarima$model$phi)
lags_ma=length(autoarima$model$theta)
spec=ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", submodel="GJRGARCH", 
       garchOrder = c(1, 0)),mean.model =list(armaOrder= c(lags_ar,lags_ma) 
       ,include.mean = TRUE), distribution.model= "norm") 
model=ugarchfit(spec,stoxx50,solver = "hybrid")
```

now if i want to fix ar1 and ar2 to zero ***manually*** ,the involved code is,and it works correctly:

```
   setfixed(spec)<- list(ar1=0,ar2=0)
   refinedmodel = ugarchfit(spec, stoxx50, solver="hybrid")
```

but when i´m trying to make it work ***automaticly***, the involved code doesn´t work:

```
  position_no_signifi = which(model@fit$robust.matcoef[,4]>0.05)

  setfixed(spec)=parse(text=paste(rownames(model@fit$matcoef)[position_no_signifi],"=",0 ))
```

Looking forward to receive your help,guys,thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this is not a question about statistics, but rather a particular problem with code. Also, when you say that it "doesn't work" you should tell us what happens instead. Any error messages?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, "doesn´t work" i mean no parameters was fixed, the refined model results the same as the original one. Sorry for ask in wrong place, i´m new and just saw there are tags what I need, so post question here.